# How to update RbConfig following OS X update

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm trying to use `RbConfig::CONFIG['host']` to get information about the current version of OS X. On a machine using Ruby that was compiled on Yosemite (Darwin 14) but subsequently upgraded to El Capitan (Darwin 15), `RbConfig::CONFIG` still reports a version of Darwin 14.

I can switch to parsing the return value of `uname -a`, but I'd rather use a Ruby-native solution. Is there a way to update `RbConfig::CONFIG` without recompiling and reinstalling Ruby?

**UPDATE**

I found all the keys in `RbConfig::CONFIG` listed out in Ruby's `configure` script. It appears that each of the values is assigned inside `configure`. I can't see yet how that list of key-value pairs is serialized into the `CONFIG` constant.

Comment: Pretty sure that config can only give you information on the state of the machine when it was compiled, as that's baked into the `ruby` binary and associated libraries. What's wrong with `uname`? There's a few libraries that will break out that information for you if that's more convenient.

Comment: I only put that out there as my take on things. I was thinking someone else would have a more concrete answer, like based on examining the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your ruby installation.

### You use the Ruby.Framework provided by Apple.

**You have nothing to do.**
I checked on both an iMac (early 2013) and a MBP (early 2015):

```
$ rbenv local system
$ rbenv rehash
$ irb
> RbConfig::CONFIG['host']
   => "x86_64-apple-darwin15"
```

Actually there is `rbconfig.rb` file which contains these settings :

```
grep "darwin15" /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/rbconfig.rb
  TOPDIR = File.dirname(__FILE__).chomp!("/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15")
  CONFIG["arch"] = "universal-darwin15"
  CONFIG["target_os"] = "darwin15"
  CONFIG["target"] = "universal-apple-darwin15"
  CONFIG["host_os"] = "darwin15"
  CONFIG["host"] = "x86_64-apple-darwin15"
  CONFIG["build_os"] = "darwin15"
  CONFIG["build"] = "x86_64-apple-darwin15"
```

You can't modify it because of System Intregrity Protection which is good.

### You use a downloaded and compiled ruby version obtained from rvm,rbenv,whatever.

I can't provide a generic solution but here is what I did (I use rbenv).

```
$ rbenv local 2.2.3

$ rbenv rehash

# What is the config?
$ ruby -e 'p RbConfig::CONFIG["host"]'
"x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0"

# Where is this?
$ grep -nir "x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0" ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby
~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:191:  CONFIG["host"] = "x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0"
~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:198:  CONFIG["build"] = "x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0"

# Change the CONFIG values according to your needs
$ vi ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/rbconfig.rb

$ ruby -e 'p RbConfig::CONFIG["host"]'
"x86_64-apple-darwin42"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Editing the `rbconfig.rb` will achieve the goal of forcing `RbConfig::CONFIG` to return the value I want, so this is technically correct. However, I think @Gustavo's answer addresses an important point, which is "you shouldn't do that," and now that I see the explanation, I have to agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is what the `RbConfig::CONFIG['host']` is supposed to return AFAIC: the OS version where ruby was built upon, not the current OS version. If you think it over it makes sense: there might be libraries or some internal components that need to make sure that your current ruby version was linked against certain library versions so say that something is not currently supported at built time if you use v15 but it was (and is) on version v14 so the fact that you already built it on an earlier version will make it work regardless of the OS upgrade, of course this is just a possible scenario, not saying it is actually true for this particular case. If you change that and force ruby to report that it was built on your current OS (or with some other library versions linked to it for that matter) which was not the case then you may break things for sure.

Why not make a simple function that does it, like you said, using `uname -r`? That would work just fine, I know is not the exact answer you were asking for but I exposed my reasoning above already:

```
require "open3"

def detect_os
  cmd = "uname -r"

  Open3.popen3 cmd do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    error = stderr.read 
    raise StandardError.new("Error while detecting OS: '#{error}'") unless error.empty?
    stdout.read
  end
end

puts detect_os
```

Comment: This answer brings up a great point and best addresses the underlying issue correctly, I think. I'm more likely to implement something like `detect_current_os` using [config.guess](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.2.1/src/config.guess) rather than `uname`, since that is the same tool that Ruby's `configure` uses to begin with. The point that there's purposely a difference between "current os" and "original build os" is very well taken, though.